Assigning a different header to return for different post categories, using PHP
I'm using PHP and Genesis Simple Hooks to assign a different header for different post categories. Works great when a post only uses ONE category. However, when I have a post that has multiple categories selected, I'm getting multiple headers loading to my page. I want to have some way to allow for multiple categories and when that happens have a way to only display one header.
SO for this post https://baker.utk.edu/how-can-we-disagree-better that has been assigned the category news AND the category podcast-season-4, I'm getting two headers. What I'd like is to have some way to say, in my array, that if my post has the categories news AND podcast-season-4 assigned, it will not be assigned the news header.
Below are the two php strings I'm using in my Genesis Simple Hook that are resulting in the double header.
**STRING ONE
**
<?php
$post = $wp_query->post;
if ( in_category ( array ( 'news' , 'featured-news'  )  ) ) {
    echo
'<div class="wrap"><div class="entry-content">
<h1 class="wp-block-heading graya"><a href="https://baker.utk.edu/news-and-events/news-archive/">News</a></h1>
</div></div>
';
}

    ?>

**STRING TWO
**
<?php
$post = $wp_query->post;
if ( in_category ( array ( 'podcast-season-4'  ) ) ) {
    echo
'<div class="wrap"><div class="entry-content"><a href="https://baker.utk.edu/news-and-events/podcast/"><div class="wp-block-cover__inner-container is-layout-flow wp-block-cover-is-layout-flow">
<figure class="wp-block-image alignleft size-large is-resized podcast-icon" ><img decoding="async" src="https://baker.utk.edu/wp-content/uploads/2024/02/YMBR.Logo_.Smokey.Slant_.svg" alt="You Might Be Right Logo" class="wp-image-8490" style="width:90px;height:auto"></figure></a>

<h1 class="wp-block-heading graya"><a href="https://baker.utk.edu/news-and-events/podcast/">Podcast</a></h1>
</div></div></div>
';
}

?>

Thanks for any help you might offer!

Have you tried using elseif or changing to switch statements to stop the logic after you find the first (most important) category you want?

elseif works beautifully! Thank you so much.
